# "We're just missing the flowers"

Tags: continuous

From [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bn8R2Y35B58) video at around 2:56:

> Chocolate, candles, champagne. We're just missing the flowers.

Why is continuous used here? Flowers are either here or not, so it is a state.

Comment: It's not the state of us that is described but the state of the flowers. The flowers are missing. Its standard idiomatic phrasing. Be careful not to get too hung up on "rules" about verbs having to describe states and things like that — think of them as guidelines.

Comment: Because you are talking about present time.

Answer (score 1):

> We just missed the flowers.

This is natural at the end of a list of what was and wasn't properly arranged.

- *We planned this party well.  We remembered the cake.  We remembered the balloons.  We just missed the flowers.*

---

> We are just missing the flowers.

This is appropriate when we are talking about how things stand at *this* moment  (as opposed to what it took to get it all together.) *"We are missing"* functions as the opposite of *"We have."*

- *This is a great party!  We have cake!  We have balloons!  We are just missing the flowers.*